# Logging Entity Framework stored procedure calls and parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, logging

I've been trying to find some code to the do the following but can't seem to hit the right google terms.  W

We have code that calls stored procedures through Entity Framework 6.0+.  Ideally, we would like to log (to console for example) the call & it's parameters (we had similar code with the old ADO.net methods)

```
using (myContext ctx = new Context())
{
   // the .Log() is just a way I'm imagining logging the call.
   ctx.Log().CallMyStoredProcedure(param1, param2, param3);
}
```

What I would like to see captured would be the following

- Stored procedure `CallMyStoredProcedure` was called with the following parameters - @Parameter1 = param1, @Parameter2 = param2, @Parameter3 = param3

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.  I gave it a test and it worked like a charm.  Post it as the answer and I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Entity Framework 6 onwards you can intercept the database call in code, this then allows you to do any logging you may need.

See this for exact details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that? Having a more descriptive answer will provide users with a better understanding on how your answer can help people with the same problem.